# How to get the form name dynamically?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have many forms that are dynamically created and each form is ends with a number which is incremental. Each form has a submit button which also has a dynamically assigned name.

I am using the following code to call a function but its limited to only one form. Is there anyway to customize it so it dynamically uses the form name assigned? I also need the form name saved to a variable.

**The jQuery**

```
    $("myform0").submit(function (e) {
        //Stops the submit request
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //checks for the button click event
    $("#submit0").click(function (e) {
        callfunction();
    });
```

**The HTML**

```
<form name="myform0">
  <input type="hidden" name="caseid" value="5008000000oYdXIAA0">
  <input type="submit" name="submit0" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So you're not wanting to submit the form, you're wanting to make it run through a custom function first?

Comment: yes, but only one form will be submitted at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a custom function instead of the submit request, you should call the function inside of the submit listener. Since you need the form name, you need to refer to `$(this)`:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    // Stops the submit request
    e.preventDefault();

    // this refers to the form that is submitted
    var formName = $(this).attr("name");

    // Call the function
    callfunction();
});
```

If you want to apply it to only the one form, change the submit selector to `$("[name='myform0']")`

Comment: thank you. this helps but i think i also need to set the form name as a variable. how would i do this following your first option ?

Comment: @user3436467 Edited to compensate